# Can't upload image to S3 using Froala

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, froala

I've been trying for a day, but I can't fix it. It got this error in console.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/My-bucket. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And this is my code on Angular2

```
imageUploadToS3: {

bucket: 'flagfrog-article-cloud',
region: 's3-us-east-2',
keyStart: 'article-image/',
params: {
  acl: 'public-read', // ACL according to Amazon Documentation.
  AWSAccessKeyId: 'AKIAJEMDZVXVLMPDNA4A', // Access Key from Amazon.
  policy: 'Policy1498724219240', // Policy string computed in the backend.
  signature: 'flagfrogweb', // Signature computed in the backend.
}
```

This is my CORS configuration on Amazon S3.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
`
```

Am I missing something here? Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Amazon doesn't allow wildcard origin. Your CORS configuration should be something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:4200</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: I did try that you suggested me. It doesn't work. still have the same error.
Does * mean allow every wildcard ?

Comment: Amazon doesn't allow `*` for AllowedOrigin. You should put the URL of the page instead.

Comment: Now I got other error instead. It's "OPTIONS https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/flagfrog-article-cloud 403 (Forbidden)". When I click it, it show "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.". Any suggestion ? Thank a lot

Comment: Most likely the signature is not computed correctly. See [here](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor-node-sdk/blob/master/lib/s3.js) and example for computing the signature with Node.